# Create iOS binding for Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a iOS library (.a and .h) which I would like to use with my Xamarin Forms project. I tried using [Xamarin's tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=macos) without any luck. I have created a bindings project and am stuck in creating the AppDefinition.cs properly (I think). I CANNOT use Objective Sharpie as I do not have the XCode project for the library, just the .a and .h. Anyway, whenever I use my binding I get an exception saying "Unrecognised selector sent to instance".

Following is my .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface EPM002Lib : NSObject

+(int)ReadParamsWithToken:(const NSString *)token withSerail:(NSMutableString *)serail withSSID:(NSMutableString *)ssid withPassword:(NSMutableString *)password withSensor:(NSMutableString *)sensor withKeepAlive:(int *)keepAlive;

+(int)SetParamsWithToken:(const NSString *)token withSSID:(const NSString *)ssid withPassword:(const NSString *)password withSensor:(const NSString *)sensor withKeepAlive:(int)keepAlive;

+(int)RebootWithToken:(const NSString *)token;

@end
```

Following is my AppDefinition.cs

```
using Foundation;

namespace SensorBinding
{
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    interface EPM002Lib
    {
        [Export("ReadParams:WithToken:withSerail:withSSID:withPassword:withSensor:withKeepAlive")]
        int ReadParams(NSString token, NSMutableString serial, NSMutableString ssid, NSMutableString password, NSMutableString sensor, int keepAlive);

        [Export("RebootWithToken:")]
        int RebootWithToken(NSString token);
    }
}
```

Now I'm not sure what the right syntax should be for the ApiDefinition methods. I translated both (ReadParams and Reboot) in seperate ways, but both give me the same error.

Please let me know if I could provide more info. Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: You should follow the instruction from this step https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=macos#including-the-static-library-in-the-binding-project

Comment: I already have the fat library (.a), I just want the method name in AppDefinition :/

Comment: We can't just give you the method name, we don't have your Libraries. 
The link I sent your begins with Adding your Native Library in the Project and Right after that, it uses the Sharpie to extract what your are looking for using those .H files.

Comment: You said "I CANNOT use Objective Sharpie as I do not have the XCode project for the library, just the .a and .h" - that wrong I think, Sharpie only needs to know about your .H files. You have .a file to reference that as an Native Static Library already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the solution:

The + before the method in the .h indicates thats its a static method and has to be annotated by [Static] header in AppDefinition.

Also, each : in the header indicates a parameter and the proceeding string indicates the parameter name. Something like

```
[Static, Export("DoStuff:secondParam:thirdParam:")]
```

The above header represents a method DoStuff with 3 parameters with the last two parameters named secondParam and thirdParam.

```
using Foundation;
namespace SensorBinding
{
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    interface EPM002Lib
    {
        [Static, Export("ReadParamsWithToken:withSerail:withSSID:withPassword:withSensor:withKeepAlive:")]
        int ReadParams(NSString token, NSMutableString serial, NSMutableString ssid, NSMutableString password, NSMutableString sensor, int keepAlive);

        [Static, Export("SetParamsWithToken:withSSID:withPassword:withSensor:withKeepAlive:")]
        int SetParams(NSString token, NSMutableString ssid, NSMutableString password, NSMutableString sensor, int keepAlive);

        [Static, Export("RebootWithToken:")]
        int Reboot(NSString token);
    }
}
```

Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. Hope this helps, thanks :)